# Deploying with RVM on Linode Ubuntu 10.4 Does not install RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy with Capistrano and RVM and even though when running `cap bundler:install_bundler` which is supposed to install bundler, and succeeds. After, when running `cap deploy` it fails with an error that bundler is not installed.

```
** [out :: victorstan.com] ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
```

Any ideas why it installs bundler, but then can't find it, or installs it in the wrong place (i guess?). Thanks!

here is part of my deploy.rb script:

```
set :application,       "dinner"
set :domain,            "victorstan.com"
set :repository,        "ssh://#{domain}/~/#{application}.git"
set :use_sudo,          false
set :user,              "victorstan"  # The server's user for deploys
set :scm,               :git
set :scm_username,      "passenger"
set :deploy_to,         "/srv/www/#{application}"
set :keep_releases,     2
set :branch,            "master"
set :deploy_via,        :copy # won't make cap prompt for password when deploying
set :scm_verbose,       true
set :rvm_ruby_string,   'ruby-2.0.0-p195@dinner'
set :rvm_type,          :user
set :rvm_install_type,  :stable
set :whenever_command,  "bundle exec whenever"


require "bundler/capistrano"
require "rvm/capistrano"
require "whenever/capistrano"
```

If I try to use cap to install bundler, it works:

```
cap bundler:install_bundler
  * 2013-06-08 15:33:54 executing `bundler:install_bundler'
  * executing "gem install bundler"
    servers: ["victorstan.com"]
    [victorstan.com] executing command
 ** [out :: victorstan.com] Successfully installed bundler-1.3.5
 ** [out :: victorstan.com] 1 gem installed
    command finished in 1373ms
```

And here is the output when running `cap deploy`:

```
Switched to a new branch 'deploy'
    command finished in 984ms
  * Compressing /var/folders/w4/_6g_9lqd491_6cmhzb0kcmzh0000gn/T/20130608192600 to /var/folders/w4/_6g_9lqd491_6cmhzb0kcmzh0000gn/T/20130608192600.tar.gz
    executing locally: tar czf 20130608192600.tar.gz 20130608192600
    command finished in 53ms
    servers: ["victorstan.com"]
 ** sftp upload /var/folders/w4/_6g_9lqd491_6cmhzb0kcmzh0000gn/T/20130608192600.tar.gz -> /tmp/20130608192600.tar.gz
    [victorstan.com] /tmp/20130608192600.tar.gz
    [victorstan.com] done
  * sftp upload complete
  * executing "cd /srv/www/dinner/releases && tar xzf /tmp/20130608192600.tar.gz && rm /tmp/20130608192600.tar.gz"
    servers: ["victorstan.com"]
    [victorstan.com] executing command
    command finished in 467ms
  * 2013-06-08 15:26:05 executing `deploy:finalize_update'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * 2013-06-08 15:26:05 executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "cd /srv/www/dinner/releases/20130608192600 && bundle install --gemfile /srv/www/dinner/releases/20130608192600/Gemfile --path /srv/www/dinner/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["victorstan.com"]
    [victorstan.com] executing command
 ** [out :: victorstan.com] ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
    command finished in 598ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /srv/www/dinner/releases/20130608192600; true"
    servers: ["victorstan.com"]
    [victorstan.com] executing command
    command finished in 513ms
failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-2.0.0-p195@dinner' -c 'cd /srv/www/dinner/releases/20130608192600 && bundle install --gemfile /srv/www/dinner/releases/20130608192600/Gemfile --path /srv/www/dinner/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on victorstan.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read some more examples on setting up deploy script and i've re-arranged the order of elements of my deploy script, as well as ena

```
set :application,       "dinner"
set :domain,            "victorstan.com"
set :repository,        "ssh://#{domain}/~/#{application}.git"
set :use_sudo,          false
set :user,              "victorstan"  # The server's user for deploys
set :scm,               :git
set :scm_username,      "passenger"
set :scm_passphrase,    "*********"  # The deploy user's password
set :deploy_to,         "/srv/www/#{application}"
set :keep_releases,     2
set :branch,            "master"
set :deploy_via,        :copy # won't make cap prompt for password when deploying
set :scm_verbose,       true
set :rvm_ruby_string,   :local
set :rvm_type,          :user
set :rvm_install_type,  :stable
set :default_shell,     :bash
set :whenever_command,  "bundle exec whenever"

default_run_options[:pty] = true

# before 'deploy', 'rvm:install_ruby'
before 'deploy:setup', 'rvm:install_ruby'

require "rvm/capistrano"
require "bundler/capistrano"
require "whenever/capistrano"

role :web, domain                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, domain                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  domain, :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
```

Some notable elements that have changed:

`set :rvm_ruby_string` set to `:local`  instead of explicitly naming it: 'ruby-2.0.0-p195@dinner', not sure if this has any implication on the issue though, seems unlikely.

`set :default_shell, :bash` was another parameter I added.

And, as I mentioned, the ordering or the different DSL types might make a difference: `set` comes first, then `before` hooks, then `require` and then `role` after which comes the rest of the deploy script. Perhaps this can help someone in a similar situation.

Note, when I first tested this script I had `before 'deploy', 'rvm:install_ruby'` enabled, but I have since disabled it and the script continues to work...

Answer (score 0):

is `ruby-2.0.0-p195@dinner` installed / created on the server?

you can ensure it is with adding:

```
before 'deploy:setup', 'rvm:install_ruby'
```

more details on using `rvm-capistrano` can be found here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano#readme

Comment: Hi, thanks, yes it is installed, I do have `before 'deploy:setup', 'rvm:install_ruby'`set in my deploy script...

Comment: then please post whole deploy script, there can be something relevant that changes how it is running.